# MySQL Multiple Subquery on same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table of the following structure

```
ID | Amount | Bank (1 or 2)
---+--------+------
1  | 100000 | 1
2  | 256415 | 2
3  | 142535 | 1
1  | 214561 | 2
2  | 123456 | 1
1  | 987654 | 2
```

I want a result like this (from the same table):

```
ID | sum(Bank 1) | sum(Bank 2)
---+-------------+------------
1  | 100000      | 1202215
2  | 123456      | 256415
3  | 142535      | 0
```

What will be the easiest query to achieve this?

Comment: we need the tables structures and your current queries to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ANSI solution:

```
Select Id
  , Sum( Case When Bank = 1 Then Amount End ) As Bank1Total
  , Sum( Case When Bank = 2 Then Amount End ) As Bank2Total
From SourceTable
Group By Id
```

[SQL Fiddle Version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a6e2/5) (using MySQL)

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I didn't think of case earlier. I was able to get the same with if:

`select id,sum(if bank=1,amount,0) as bank1total,sum(if bank=2,amount,0) as bank2total from table group by id`

Comment: If the number of case is less than 3 its better to use `IF` than `CASE`

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - `Case` is ANSI standard. IMO, you should always prefer the ANSI standard over a proprietary solution unless the performance difference is significant and I doubt it is.

Answer (score 1):

This SQL query will pull the information you are looking for:

```
select ID, 
       SUM(IF(Bank=1, Amount, 0)) AS Bank1,
       SUM(IF(Bank=2, Amount, 0)) AS Bank2
from TableName
group by ID ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd1bb/6) with tsql I was able to come up with:

```
select distinct t.id,
      isnull((select sum(t1.amount) 
         from temp as t1
         where t.id = t1.id and t1.bank = 1), 0) as 'bank 1 sum',
      isnull((select sum(t1.amount) 
         from temp as t1
         where t.id = t1.id and t1.bank = 2), 0) as 'bank 2 sum'
  from temp as t
```

where temp is your table name. For mySQL (Thanks to @JakeFeasel in the comments):

```
select distinct t.id,
      ifnull((select sum(t1.amount) 
         from temp as t1
         where t.id = t1.id and t1.bank = 1), 0) as 'bank 1 sum',
      ifnull((select sum(t1.amount) 
         from temp as t1
         where t.id = t1.id and t1.bank = 2), 0) as 'bank 2 sum'
  from temp as t
```

Comment: OP is using MySQL, not MS SQL

Comment: Here is a very similar fiddle using MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67618/2 (just had to change isnull to ifnull)

Comment: Yes but I figured this would help him approach the solution. Thanks @JakeFeasel